# If search returns nothing give error

Tags: php, mysql

I have a search form on my website, and I want it to return an error if the user searches for something that does not exist in my database

```
<?php

$search = $_POST['search' ];

$numrows = mysql_num_rows ($result );

if($numrows != 0) echo "No results";
?>
```

This is the code that my search form is using, however the echo"no results" shows on the homepage above all of the results, but does not display when there are no results from the search.

I'm a beginner to PHP, so I am completely unsure why this is happening.

If you need my full code, it is below:

http://pastebin.com/xjxwhfDT

Comment: if($numrows != 0) echo "No results"; may be you want this if($numrows == 0)

Comment: You've got your test backwards.

Answer (score 1):

wouldn't it be

```
if($numrows == 0) echo "No results";
```

if nothing is found ?

- your  `$numrows = mysql_num_rows ($result );` shouldn't be at the place it actually is.

You should do something like :

```
$count = count($result);
if($count > 0)
{
    while ($row =mysql_fetch_object ($result)) {
        // do your stuff
    }
}
else
{
    echo 'no results';
}
```

also, what is the point of `$search = $_POST['search' ];` in your while loop? You don't seem to use it at all.

Comment: That works to the point of removing the text above all of the results, but it still doesn't display the error on the page when no results are found from the search.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:-

```
        $numrows = mysql_num_rows ($result );
        if($numrows > 0){

        while ($row =mysql_fetch_object ($result)) {

        //- Main Content -

        echo '<div class="wrapper">';
        ?>
         <?php

         //--------- GET THE POST HTML VARIABLES. PUT INTO PHP VARIABLES -----------------------------

         $search = $_POST['search' ];

            }
    // write your whlie loop code here
    }else{
        echo "No results";
        }
```

`mysql_num_rows` Retrieves the number of rows from a result set. Check number of row greater then 0 or not

Comment: The "no results" text doesn't show on the page when there are no results returned from the search.

Comment: @CallumWatson you check this condition inside your while loop thats is wrong . check it before while loop. i edit my code .

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, given the code. I would ask if $result contains a query result?

ie.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table1", $link);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

Secondly, [mysql_num_rows()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php) returns number of rows or FALSE. So, double check if $results is a valid result set from a valid query.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

move your if before the while and it works

Now

```
while ($row =mysql_fetch_object ($result)) {
[...]
 $numrows = mysql_num_rows ($result );
 if($numrows != 0)
[...]
```

Correct

```
$numrows = mysql_num_rows ($result );
if($numrows == 0){ echo 'no result'; die();}
while ($row =mysql_fetch_object ($result)) 
[...]
```

Because if result is empty while loop is not executed.

Comment: This works but it displays the error even before the user searches.

Comment: edit `if($numrows==0)` with `if($numrows==0 and isset($_POST['search']))`

Comment: That removed the pre-search, but now it doesn't show the message when you search; updated code:

http://pastebin.com/gbjAfxKG

Comment: add input hidden in form and check if it is set :)